# Android wallpaper issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-ndk

I am trying to set the wallpaper through an application with the following code:

```
        buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                    .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.five);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

It works fine and the drawable image 'five' is being set as wallpaper on button click.
But when I uninstall this APK which sets the wallpaper, I need to  revert back to the default/previous wallpaper itself.

Why on deleting this APK, the wallpaper does not get reverted. What is the fix I have for this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Anees

Answer (score 1):

That's because as soon as you set wallpaper via WallpaperManager, it converts requested image into a file and saves to system directory.(you can find its implementation [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/WallpaperManager.java#WallpaperManager.setResource%28int%29))

Well, I don't have any idea that reset default wallpaper when user uninstalling your app, I recommend you to put another button or find a way to get a default wallpaper.